this.close() is not closing the modal. What am I doing wrong?
I have created an LWC which is opened by a quick Action. The lwc extends lightning modal. Now I have a cancel which calls the handler function that is supposed to close the modal using this.close(). But it is not doing anything. Here is the code. This is a work in progress by the way.
html file
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header label="Delete"></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body>
        <template if:true={isScreen1}>
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
            <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Delete the linked Work Items?" onchange={handleRelatedChange}></lightning-input>
        </template>
        <template if:true={isConfirmationScreen}>
            <p>This will delete all the linked Work Items. Do you want to proceed?</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button variant="destructive" label="Delete" onclick={confirmDelete}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>

js file
import { LightningElement,api, track } from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';
export default class DevopsReleaseDeleteButton extends LightningModal {
    //@track showModal = true;
    @track deleteRelatedRecords = false;
    @api recordId;
    //@api objectApiName;
    @track currentScreen = 1;
    get isScreen1(){
        return this.currentScreen == 1;
    }
    get isConfirmationScreen(){
        return this.currentScreen == 2;
    }
    handleRelatedChange(event){
        this.deleteRelatedRecords = event.target.checked;
    }
    handleCancel(){
        this.close();
    }
    confirmDelete(){
        this.currentScreen = 2;
    }
}


I don't think there's anything wrong with your this.close(). There must be some problem with some Javascript that is executed before and that fails (or some markup problem, e.g. iterators without keys etc.). Scan your Chrome DevTools for errors and even dubious warnings!

Please try CloseActionScreenEvent: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-quick-actions-screen.html

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This is the error you get when you click on "The LightningOverlay extended component is closed or in the process of closing. this.close() was previously called.". To over come this issue update your code with a variable to control view and hide of the component.
import { LightningElement,api, track } from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';
export default class DevopsReleaseDeleteButton extends LightningModal {
//@track showModal = true;
@track deleteRelatedRecords = false;
@api recordId;
showAndHide = true;
//@api objectApiName;
@track currentScreen = 1;
get isScreen1(){
    return this.currentScreen == 1;
}
get isConfirmationScreen(){
    return this.currentScreen == 2;
}
handleRelatedChange(event){
    this.deleteRelatedRecords = event.target.checked;
}
handleCancel(){
    this.showAndHide = false;
   // this.close();
}
confirmDelete(){
    this.currentScreen = 2;
}
}


<template>
<template if:true={showAndHide}>
    <lightning-modal-header label="Delete"></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body>
        <template if:true={isScreen1}>
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
            <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Delete the linked Work Items?" onchange={handleRelatedChange}></lightning-input>
        </template>
        <template if:true={isConfirmationScreen}>
            <p>This will delete all the linked Work Items. Do you want to proceed?</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button variant="destructive" label="Delete" onclick={confirmDelete}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>

